# EFS not working properly on Windows 10 Pro in Bootcamp on a MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, windows-10, mac, encryption, boot-camp

I have a MacBook Pro and I ran Bootcamp to install Windows 10 Pro x64. All is well with both OS's. I know that I can't encrypt the entire Bootcamp drive, but everything I've read points to being able to use EFS to encrypt a folder, which is sufficient for me.

I encrypted a folder, it went through the process, but never showed the directory as green. To confirm that it did not work, I booted to the OSX partition and was able to open all the folders on the Bootcamp partition, including the folder that has encryption turned on. That tells me that the folder is not properly encrypted.

Other documentation talked about using efsinfo.exe, but I don't find it on my Bootcamp drive and the link to it from Microsoft is no longer available.

I hope I'm not missing something simple or stupid. I have used this before. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Open all to folders, sure, but how about the files?

Comment: No, I can't open the files, but I can go through the entire directory structure and even see the names.  The names themselves are confidential and would pose a security risk.  And still, it's not showing the folder in the color green to indicate it is encrypted (the folder or the files).

Comment: The color is based on a setting, that might be off. And only contents of files are encrypted, not folders or names. So it's not suitable to hide all information of files' existence.

Comment: I found more info to answer other questions I had about EFS, but I think that not having the entire directory structure encrypted to be inaccessible will probably preclude me from using that solution.  I will look at the third party encryption solution.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately EFS works on file level and not folder level. The contents of folders will stay readable even after encryption, only the file contents will be encrypted.

Since you cannot encrypt the whole drive the only option is to use some other product to handle the encryption to hide also the filenames and other metadata.

The missing coloring of the folders may be due to settings, it may not have been turned on.